# get n value in redis with python

Tags: python, json, redis

`values = self.redisClient.client.json().get(r_key[0], f'{r_key[1]}.values.{type}')`

using this line, I can get all values under r_key in redis. but I want to get this data in a certain size. So I don't want to install them all at once. I'll buy the last 50, then I'll buy another 50 whenever I want.

For example, there are 150 values here, instead of reading these 150 values and then using them, I want to pull 50 by 50 from the redis and use them that way. So when this number increases I won't have a problem

I tried "scan" but I did not reach what i want.